# How to derive the effective Langrangian of matter field, say, fermi field and quasiparticle, say, spin wave?

Tags: condensed-matter

In the Fermi-Hubbard model, it may lead to spin wave due to SO(3) symmetry breaking. I know how to derive the effective Lagrangian for the spin wave by integrating out the Fermi fields. However, how to derive a Lagrangian for the Fermi fields term, spin wave dynamic term and their interaction ?
An example,
[image]

Comment: What do you mean, *"derive"* the Lagrangian? The Lagrangian is *assumed*, it is the starting point of any (well, most) QFTs, it is not *derived*, though one can often tell which terms may not occur through symmetry considerations.

Comment: I mean the effective theory. For example, starting from a Fermi Hubbard model, it may be obtain the effective model about the spin wave when one consider the spin fluctuation and integrate out the fermi field.